# Online trading is halal or haram?

Tags: practical-islam, sharia, investment

Aslamualikum..
I want to know that investment in currency market and commodity exchange via stocksons company is halal or haram?

Answer (score 0):

It is halal but to be safe you should do sadaqah in order to stay awar from haram.

Comment: This answer is entirely opinion based. Please provide facts and references that support your answer.